# kubernetes traefik ingress 503 bad gateway error

Tags: kubernetes, traefik-ingress, k3s

As I want to learn to deploy software with kubernetes, I installed a single node k3s cluster (ip: 192.168.178.10) with `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -`. Now I followed [this](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ingress-guide-nginx-example.html) tutorial to get two services up and expose them to the outside. But when i try `curl 192.168.178.10/apple` the responce is `Bad Gateway` I think it has something to do with the k3s traefik ingeress, but i wasn't able to locate the problem.

services

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: banana-app
  labels:
    app: banana
spec:
  containers:
    - name: banana-app
      image: hashicorp/http-echo
      args:
        - "-text=banana"

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: banana-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: banana
  ports:
    - port: 5678 # Default port for image
```

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apple-app
  labels:
    app: apple
spec:
  containers:
    - name: apple-app
      image: hashicorp/http-echo
      args:
        - "-text=apple"

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apple-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: apple
  ports:
    - port: 5678 # Default port for image
```

ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple
          backend:
            serviceName: apple-service
            servicePort: 5678
        - path: /banana
          backend:
            serviceName: banana-service
            servicePort: 5678
```

---

Edit:
`kubectl describe ingress example-ingress` shows th following rules:

```
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     
        /apple    apple-service:5678 (10.42.0.68:5678)
        /banana   banana-service:5678 (10.42.0.67:5678)
```

while thoise are the services for apple and banana:

```
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
apple-service    ClusterIP   10.43.61.250   <none>        5678/TCP   101m
banana-service   ClusterIP   10.43.67.205   <none>        5678/TCP   100m
```

The ip's don't match what seems like a problem for me.

---

output of `kubectl describe svc`:

```
 Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
                   provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.43.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        6443/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.178.10:6443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>


Name:              banana-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"banana-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":5...
Selector:          app=banana
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.43.124.19
Port:              <unset>  5678/TCP
TargetPort:        5678/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.0.76:5678
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>


Name:              apple-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"apple-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":56...
Selector:          app=apple
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.43.9.134
Port:              <unset>  5678/TCP
TargetPort:        5678/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.0.77:5678
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: are you sure the syntax is correct? I've never had the need to use Ingress, so can't talk from the experience, but according to the docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/, the `backend` syntax is not correct.

Comment: I checked it with the [minimal ingress](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/service/networking/minimal-ingress.yaml), but that leads to an error, while my file gets applied without any warning or error.

Comment: Could you please add output from `kubectl describe svc` of your traefik ingress service?